# Failed linking passenger 5.0.23 native support with Ruby 2.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am trying to make a clean APT install of Passenger latest stable `5.0.23` with Ruby `2.2.4` on Ubuntu 14.0.4 but I keep getting `[passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download)`. I've successfully compiled by hand the actual `.so`:

```
 ➜  ~  passenger-config build-native-support 
 [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Compilation succesful. The logs are here:
     /tmp/passenger_native_support-1h838u1.log
 [passenger_native_support.so] successfully loaded.
➜  ~  cat /tmp/passenger_native_support-1h838u1.log
# mkdir -p /root/.passenger/native_support/5.0.23/ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-linux
# cd /root/.passenger/native_support/5.0.23/ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-linux
# /usr/bin/ruby2.2 /usr/share/passenger/ruby_extension_source/extconf.rb
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for ruby/version.h... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for ruby_version... no
checking for rb_thread_io_blocking_region() in ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
creating Makefile
# make
compiling /usr/share/passenger/ruby_extension_source/passenger_native_support.c
linking shared-object passenger_native_support.so
```

But, it's still failing in Nginx:

```
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4123 1055/7f247600d7c0 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1276 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4406 1070/7f106e3067c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:957 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4407 1070/7f106e3067c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:234 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4423 1070/7f106e3067c0 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:707 ]: Passenger core online, PID 1070
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4475 1078/7f1c642e37c0 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:504 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-01-19 14:23:45.4480 1078/7f1c642e37c0 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:317 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 1078
App 1586 stdout: 
App 1586 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 1586 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 1586 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 1586 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 1586 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.23/rubyext-ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
App 1586 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 1586 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.23/rubyext-ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
App 1586 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
App 1586 stderr:   --> Passenger will still operate normally.
App 1607 stdout:
```

Neither tarball archives exist on Passenger servers or S3.

The actual Rails app works fine but I don't mind spending time finding the root causes of this warning. Any idea about where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a workaround!

The issues was the `.so` wasn't accessible to the `nobody` user which was running Passenger. I've troubled compiling anything with the `nobody` user, so I've ended up just copying the `.so` from the root folder to `/usr/lib/`:

```
cp /root/.passenger/native_support/5.0.23/ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-linux/passenger_native_support.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.2.0/passenger_native_support.so
```

I don't know if it's the cleanest thing ever but it's working.